# Iterate over GeoPandas rows to translate multipoints by different values

Tags: python, geopandas

I would like to iterate over each row in a GeoPandas multipoint dataframe to translate each point by different x, y values as such:

```
x = [numpy array of x translations of length of dataframe] ex: [5,10,6,8,...]
y = [numpy array of y translations of length of dataframe]

for index, poi in test1.iterrows():
    test1.loc[index, 'geometry'] = test1.loc[index, 'geometry'].translate(xoff=x[index], yoff=y[index])
```

I'm getting the error: `AttributeError: 'MultiPoint' object has no attribute 'translate'`

As a note: it will run using

```
for index, poi in test1.iterrows():
    test1['geometry'].translate(xoff=x[index], yoff=y[index])
```

but ultimately moves all the points over and over.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GeoPandas [`translate`](https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.translate) is a method of `GeoSeries`. In your case you must import shapely and then use its [`translate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.affinity.translate) function on the geometry. This should work:

```
from shapely.affinity import translate

tmp = []
for index, poi in test1.iterrows():
    new_point = translate(test1.loc[index, 'geometry'], xoff=x[index], yoff=y[index])
    tmp.append({'geometry':new_point, 'other_stuff':test1.loc[index, 'other_col']...})

test2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(tmp)
```

Comment: @Amanda I haven't tested this. If it works for you, please mark the answer as solution.

Comment: It is creating a pandas error like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52552198/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-pandas-column-as-list/52563718#52563718

Comment: And the import is from shapely.affinity import translate

Comment: I used this technique along with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345167/building-geodataframe-row-by-row to just construct a new geopandas dataframe.